# COMException using ODBC while trying to list "Views" in Codesmith

Tags: mysql, odbc, comexception, codesmith

I have established an ODBC connection to a MySQL Server (ODBC driver version 5.1 by Oracle). The connection test succeeds! If I click to show the TABLES of the database it succeeds as well. Now I am trying to show the VIEWS and I get the following error:

```
Das Objekt oder der Provider kann den angeforderten Vorgang nicht ausführen.
(Translated: Object or provider is not capable of performing requested operation.)

An error of type "COMException" occurred while attempting to populate schema 
information.  Please check your data source settings and try again.

-----------------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0CB3): 

Das Objekt oder der Provider kann den angeforderten Vorgang nicht ausführen
(Translated: Object or provider is not capable of performing requested operation.)
at ADOX.Views.get_Count()
at SchemaExplorer.ADOXSchemaProvider.GetViews(String connectionString, DatabaseSchema database)
at SchemaExplorer.CachedSchemaProviderProxy.GetViews(String connectionString, DatabaseSchema database)
at SchemaExplorer.DatabaseSchema.#EGe()
at #UHd.#vJd.#XHd()
at #UHd.#5Hd.#4Hd()
```

A similar error occures when trying to list table columns,keys or index:

```
at (ADOX.Tables.get_Item(Object Item) 
at SchemaExplorer.ADOXSchemaProvider.GetTableIndexes(String connectionString, TableSchema table)
at SchemaExplorer.TableSchema.#sHe()
at #UHd.#zId.#XHd()
at #UHd.#5Hd.#4Hd()
```

Aditional Information:
Windows 7, 64 Bits
MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver

I tried to include the Codesmith directory to my windows PATH environment var without success.
Any ideas? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MySQLSchemaProvider instead of the ADOXSchemaProvider. The MySQLSchemaProvider ships with Generator.